# How to set JVM maximum heap memory for Apache Ignite v1.7?

Tags: java, jvm, ignite

How do I set the maximum heap memory available to Apache Ignite when running via `ignite.sh`? The docs do not seem to cover this very basic task. Also, how do I verify that the setting is actually working?

I have read that the command line option `-J` is available for passing JVM arguments from `ignite.sh` to the JVM process, but am unable to find evidence it is actually working. For example, if I start Ignite as follows:

```
bin/ignite.sh -v -J-Xmx2g
```

The program outputs the following message:

```
[09:13:42,422][INFO][main][IgniteKernal] VM arguments: [-Xms1g, -Xmx1g, -XX:+AggressiveOpts, -XX:MaxPermSize=256m, -DIGNITE_QUIET=false, -DIGNITE_SUCCESS_FILE=/Users/landon/Downloads/apache-ignite-fabric-1.7.0-bin/work/ignite_success_5d0c3958-8952-4a7d-81b0-76c07ae6c520, -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote, -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=49164, -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false, -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false, -DIGNITE_HOME=/Users/landon/Downloads/apache-ignite-fabric-1.7.0-bin, -DIGNITE_PROG_NAME=bin/ignite.sh, -Xmx2g]
```

Which seems to suggest both `-Xmx1g` and `-Xmx2g` are being passed.

Also, `ps aux` shows the following:

```
landon          47582   1.0  2.1  5214944 172616 s000  S+    9:13AM   0:06.19 /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -Xms1g -Xmx1g -server -XX:+AggressiveOpts -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -DIGNITE_QUIET=false -Xdock:name=Ignite Node -DIGNITE_SUCCESS_FILE=/Users/landon/Downloads/apache-ignite-fabric-1.7.0-bin/work/ignite_success_5d0c3958-8952-4a7d-81b0-76c07ae6c520 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=49164 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -DIGNITE_HOME=/Users/landon/Downloads/apache-ignite-fabric-1.7.0-bin -DIGNITE_PROG_NAME=bin/ignite.sh -Xmx2g -cp /Users/landon/Downloads/apache-ignite-fabric-1.7.0-bin/libs/*:/Users/landon/Downloads/apache-ignite-fabric-1.7.0-bin/libs/ignite-indexing/*:/Users/landon/Downloads/apache-ignite-fabric-1.7.0-bin/libs/ignite-spring/*:/Users/landon/Downloads/apache-ignite-fabric-1.7.0-bin/libs/licenses/* org.apache.ignite.startup.cmdline.CommandLineStartup config/default-config.xml
landon          45624   0.0  0.0  3166752   1292   ??  S    Fri07PM   0:00.01 /bin/bash bin/ignite.sh -v -J-Xmx2g
```

Which ambiguously lists both `-Xmx1g` and `-Xmx2g` on the command line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the correct way to set heap memory. If `Xmx` is listed twice, JVM will use the last one.